# RSS feed with specific keyword

Tags: wordpress, rss

I am able to get articles as RSS feed from below url

```
http://wordpress_site/blog/feed
```

I am also able to get articles from BlogSpot with specific keywords as below

```
https://www.yourblogname.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?q=KEYWORD
```

I have tried to get articles from filtering with specific KEYWORD in wordpress blog but I am not able to get. What can be the URL.

I am very much newbie to wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve an RSS feed of a search by doing so :

```
http://wordpress_site/feed/?s=your%20keyword%20here
```